# What plugins are required to run Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've tried disabling all the default plugins installed with Jenkins (using the official Jenkins docker image) but I can no longer access it via HTTP although it seems to have booted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Jenkins requires any of the default plugins.

The HTTP problem was unrelated.